# How to get the authorization code for Google drive API access programmatically?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I need to download a file from Google drive. I got the code to do that [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-cs). In this code they launch a web browser process with an URL which asks user to authorize the API access. After authorization, it provides authorization key which needs to keyed in to our process to actually continue (This is typical oath-2.0 procedure). I want make the entire procedure automated without any user interaction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try mode = offline and consent = auto

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) to get API access without user interaction, however there seems to be no official .NET implementation for it right now.

Someone created a sample [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-search-api-for-shopping/4uUGirzH4Rw/__c0e4hj0ekJ) on how to use a service account with Google Analytics in C#.